# Is this answer appropriate?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer

I was looking through the First Post queue, and I came across this answer:

[Amazon S3 static website - Redirect HTTPS to HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871111/amazon-s3-static-website-redirect-https-to-http/24874929#comment38636155_24874929)

(I posted to a comment on it, not the answer itself--side note, could someone let me know in a comment how to discover the permalink to an answer?)

I commented that it wasn't *really* an answer and gave the How to Answer link, but what is the appropriate action here? I respect the poster's attempt to help add some information to the question, but it really isn't an answer.

What's the preferred method to add on personal experience like this to another person's question?

**Edit:**

Or, just kidding. I see the answer was deleted. I don't know whether that was a result of pressure from me, or if it was deleted by a moderator or something. I don't have enough rep points to view it, but if I'm not mistaken it should be possible for someone with more to add a screenshot or something?

In any event, the answer was just adding in some details about things the poster had tried, including some CURL and DNS results.

Comment: You get a link to an answer the same way you get it from a question: just click the `share` button below it.

Comment: It was deleted by a moderator.  The "answer" just created a discussion, but didn't actually answer anything.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I guess some things start to blend in after you see them over and over again.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Fair enough. Although is there a way for someone to add those sorts of details? They wouldn't have been appropriate in a comment, since the formatting would have been positively useless. But I feel like there are some cases where a third party's input could be beneficial to finding an answer. What's the expected action in a case like that?

Comment: The text that is presented to us in the moderator dashboard is only the first few sentences of the answer, and this one probably looked like "I have the same problem" at first glance.  I went ahead and undeleted it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That was definitely the right call, I'm not disputing it at all. It wasn't an answer by any stretch. And that's why I said that in a comment. But I guess the better option for this person would have been to suggest that the OP try the same steps and edit the question. Alright. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's really not an answer, then flagging it is appropriate.  A complete answer wouldn't include what they tried or what they're continuing to try; it would be able to stand up on its own merits.

The way the answer reads is that it's trying a few things, but then that ultimately cumulates into an "I don't know, I'll keep trying solutions".  That's not what I'd consider an ideal answer to a question, let alone a complete answer.

I would personally prefer if an answer were complete, and if it did want to include what was tried or what was employed, then that's great - as long as its germane to the answering of the question.  That would exclude statements like, "Trying to request the page over HTTPS doesn't work".